# Remove ?post_type= from Wordpress URLs

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, breadcrumbs

I have use custom post type named Product in Wordpress. Using plugins Custom Permalinks, Custom Post Type Permalinks I had set URLs for categories (for this custom post type Product) as I want, for example

```
site.com/categoryname/
```

But , Breadcrumb NavXT shows in navigation links as

```
site.com/categoryname/?post_type=product
```

, because `categoryname` is used for custom post type Product.
How can I remove `?post_type=` from URLs, which Breadcrumb NavXT shows ?

Comment: https://mtekk.us/archives/guides/how-to-remove-post_type-from-breadcrumb-navxt-urls/

Comment: Annarfych, thanks!!!